# How do I reference the process PORT assignment for PM2 in my child script / process?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am experimenting with PM2 for my node.js environment on Ubunty and want to try to figure out how I can take a port number specified in the command line like the following...

```
$pm2 start test.js --node-args "port=3001 sitename='first pm2 app'"
```

... and then in my target script (test.js in the above example) and use that port number for my .listen port... for example:

```
    var express = require('express')
    var app = express()

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.send('Hello World!')
    })

    app.listen(PORT_NUM_HERE, function () {
      console.log('Example app listening on port ' + PORT_NUM_HERE + '!')
    })
```

I also see that with PM2 I can use a configuration file to define process name, port, etc. and if I do that, same question, how to take the port used in the configuration file and use it in my child script.

example configuration file:

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "futurestudio-homepage",
      "script": "./homepage/server.js",
      "instances": 2,
      "exec_mode": "cluster",
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "production",
        "PORT": "3000",
      }
    }
}
```

]
}

Comment: `process.env.port`

Comment: @CarlosSultana - I tried this and also process.env.NODE_PORT, process.env.PORT and nothing works.  I also did console.log(process) and don't see the port value at all.  I'm stumped on this one!

Comment: Hi there, I'm having this same issue, did you ever managed to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Specify environmental variable on the command line:

```
NODE_PORT=3100 pm2 start ./src/server.ts --name dev
```

PM2 can be configured by using `process.json` or `ecosystem.config.js`. [The docs are here](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/).

This should start your app on port 3100:

```
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js
```

Contents of the `ecosystem.config.js` file:

```
// ecosystem.config.js
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: "dev",
    script: "src/server.ts",
    cwd: "/root/api",
    env: {
        NODE_PORT:"3100",
        NODE_ENV:"development"
    }
  }]
}
```

Add you can test it by running something like this on your server:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:3100
```